# Open source project using Spring <Medium sized>

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, open-source, spring-mvc

I have gained some knowledge on Spring[Spring in Action] & Hibernate(through google) and want to apply the same to a Open source project so that i can learn how it is used in a real project.

When i searched on sourceforge.net for projects using Spring framework, it showed very big projects like adding enhancement to the framework or plugins..which are out of my reach considering i am a newbie to the framework.

I am

> **looking for a medium sized open source project using Spring framework,
>   to contribute as well as learn.**

NOTE: The projects like petclinic given on the springsource.org are a kind of small :)

Answer (score 4):

Search for open source ERP solutions built on Spring and Hibernate. [TNTConcept](http://java-source.net/open-source/erp-crm/tntconcept) for example. Knowledge of ERP internals will most likely help you finding a well payed job as well.